# Difference between sar -W and sar -B ?

Tags: rhel

What is the difference between the output from sar  -W and sar -B they seem to be similar but the man pages only confuse me further on this matter any who clarify this for me ?

Comment: The answer shows up in the man pages as the initial answer shows in the man page extract.  Exactly what are you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-W` switch looks to be the original switch while the `-B` switch came later on. There are notes in the man page which seem to indicate this as well. The `-B` switch has newer statistics that were exposed in a later version of the Linux kernel (post 2.5).

#### `-W` usage

> -W     Report swapping statistics. The following values are displayed:
>
> ```
>    pswpin/s
>           Total number of swap pages the system brought in per second.
>    pswpout/s
>           Total number of swap pages the system brought out per second.
> ```

#### `-B` usage

> -B     Report paging statistics. Some of the metrics below are available only with post 2.5 kernels. The following values
>          are displayed:
>
> ```
>    pgpgin/s
>           Total number of kilobytes the system paged in from disk per second.  Note: With old  kernels  (2.2.x)  this
>           value is a number of blocks per second (and not kilobytes).
>
>    pgpgout/s
>           Total  number  of  kilobytes  the system paged out to disk per second.  Note: With old kernels (2.2.x) this
>           value is a number of blocks per second (and not kilobytes).
>
>    fault/s
>           Number of page faults (major + minor) made by the system per second.  This is not a count  of  page  faults
>           that generate I/O, because some page faults can be resolved without I/O.
>
>    majflt/s
>           Number of major faults the system has made per second, those which have required loading a memory page from
>           disk.
>
>    pgfree/s
>           Number of pages placed on the free list by the system per second.
>
>    pgscank/s
>           Number of pages scanned by the kswapd daemon per second.
>
>    pgscand/s
>           Number of pages scanned directly per second.
>
>    pgsteal/s
>           Number of pages the system has reclaimed from cache (pagecache and swapcache) per  second  to  satisfy  its
>           memory demands.
>
>    %vmeff
>           Calculated as pgsteal / pgscan, this is a metric of the efficiency of page reclaim. If it is near 100% then
>           almost every page coming off the tail of the inactive list is being reaped. If it gets too low  (e.g.  less
>           than  30%)  then the virtual memory is having some difficulty.  This field is displayed as zero if no pages
>           have been scanned during the interval of time.
> ```

#### Examples

If you look at the output from the `-B` and `-W` switches that might help shed light on there differences.

**-W**

```
$ sar -W
02:50:01 PM  pswpin/s pswpout/s
03:00:01 PM      0.57      1.71
03:10:01 PM      0.31      0.02
03:20:01 PM      0.80      1.25
03:30:01 PM      0.41      0.68
03:40:01 PM      0.57      1.02
03:50:01 PM      0.88      0.00
```

**-B**

```
$ sar -B
02:50:01 PM  pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff
03:00:01 PM     96.10    615.25   6113.00      0.44   7612.77    105.80      0.00     96.48     91.19
03:10:01 PM     14.91    562.47   5250.07      0.17   7029.09     26.63      0.00     23.72     89.08
03:20:01 PM     16.95    620.39   7265.82      0.26   9115.73     92.36      0.11     83.01     89.77
03:30:01 PM     28.84    566.17   8768.76      0.21  10750.77     63.20      0.21     58.65     92.49
03:40:01 PM     16.05    641.84  10343.84      0.31  12473.88     45.40      0.11     41.01     90.11
03:50:01 PM     18.20    647.99  10272.98      0.25  12187.26      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

The differences being that the `-W` data is with respect to how many pages were swapped in & out in a second, vs. the `-B` switch which shows the aggregate amount of data (in kilobytes) that was paged in/out in a second.

Comment: Hmmm...if the user says he is confused by the man page, will he not be confused with simply an extract of the man page for sar???

Comment: Well let's see 8-).

Comment: unfortunately that does really clarify it for me.....any other takers who might be able to shed light on the difference between the two ...???

Comment: @user1380599 - See my updates and let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks for your response that did the trick all clear now ;-)

Comment: @user1380599 - Glad to hear that, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as the accepted answer so that others know that your issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

`sar -B` man pages are incorrect, in my view. According to the Linux source at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/page_io.c?v=4.6 , PSWPIN is incremented in `swap_readpage()`. If you click on the `swap_readpage()` function, you can see that it's called directly to deal with the classic Virtual Memory kernel paging (not to be confused with swapping). That is, it's used when the disk is being used as an adjunct to your system's memory.

PGPGIN is maintained in `submit_bio()` as seen here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/block/blk-core.c?v=4.6 . Click on it, and you can see that it's used for much more generic disk i/o.

So `sar -W`'s counters specify pages having to do with virtual memory ("swap" is a term that seems to be used rather loosely these days, I believe it has come to mean generally "having to do with saving chunks of processes' memory to hard disk").

`sar -B`'s counters- at least a couple of them- are updated when there is any disk i/o. Other counters, such as `fault/s`, deal with any memory pages that a process cannot immediately access (see http://linoxide.com/linux-command/commands-to-understand-page-faults-in-linux/, "...If the requested page resides in main memory but the process cannot access it because of either uninitialized memory or a COW (copy on write) page, it’s called minor page fault..."). Google can help you gain a better grasp of what exactly they are counting.